# Dualboot on 2 different SSDs

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot

I am looking to make a dualboot with the following setup

-120 GB Samsung SSD (Currently windows 10 primary disk) \

-120 GB AMD SSD (empty) \

-1T Seagate HDD (secondary disk in NTFS format for windows primary disk)

I want to install Linux (preferrably KDE or Mint or Arch) on 120 GB AMD SSD and keep windows on 120 GB Samsung SSD.

I have tried in many ways, but the booting is terrible. I installed 6-7 different distros of linux.
Would it be better to create a Raid 0 between the 2 SSD's and reinstall Windows and Linux on the same Raid Disk?

Comment: How is booting terrible? I have several systems with multiple OS's across multiple drives and have no issues. Can you be more specific about the issues your having?

Comment: what bootloader are you using?

Comment: Well, I haven't particularly used a bootloader. I have managed to install it once, with Mint, and it booted, but only when I have manually selected the drive itself. Otherwise, the system would boot into windows, but when I try to boot into linux, it just stops. A white cursor on a black background blinks on and on and nothing happens.